# How to get the data displayed of one Visual Force page into another Visual Force page

Tags: visualforce, quote

I have created a custom visual force page .Now i would like to get Data of another visual force page displayed in the Custom visual force page .Can we achieve this.Any suggestion plz.

Mu Custom VF page is on "Quote Object".I tried using the  tag on my custom VF page .i get an Error  as 
Id value 0Q0J0000000HoRd is not valid for the Opportunity standard controller .

Comment: @JennyB:The Visual force page is of an intsalled package.So can i get the data to custom visual force page which is in PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the apex:include tag found in the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_include.htm).

> **apex:include**
>
> A component that inserts a second Visualforce page into the current page. The entire page subtree is injected into the Visualforce DOM at the point of reference and the scope of the included page is maintained.